# Customize Gradle Visual-Studio Plugin to Generate vcxproj.user

Tags: gradle

I am trying to customize default Visual-Studio Gradle Plugin tasks to generate a vcxproj.user file along the vcxproj file for every project in a solution that is an executable (I want to skip libraries).

The idea was to find all tasks that are of type GenerateProjectFileTask, somehow filter only those that represent an executable binary (this part I don't know how to do yet) and a finalizedBy clause to make them run my task that will also generate the .user file.

I need this since my project has a custom `Working Directory` path and I have to regenerate the project each time I add new source files etc. and obviously when I do so (after clean) I have to set those paths again for each executable. This is pretty annoying.

What I was trying to do so far was

```
subprojects {
    // every proejct with plugin cpp also uses visual-studio plugin
    plugins.withId('cpp') {
        afterEvaluate {
            tasks.withType(GenerateProjectFileTask) { task ->
                def project = task.getVisualStudioProject()
                if(project != null) {
                    println project.projectFile.location
               }
               else {
                   println "Project is null"
               }
               //println task.getOutputFile().getPath() <- this didnt work either
               task.finalizedBy "someGeneratedTaskForEachProjectToCreateUserProperties"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it always prints `Project is null` and I don't understand why. I need the path to know where to generate the file.

Also I dont like the finalizedBy clause since it always run no matter if the finalized task failed or not. Is there a better solution to this problem?

In short what I want to achieve is when I run a task for instance: `gradlew demoAppVisualStudio`  it should generate not only solution and all necessary projects but also run my generated tasks for projects that represent executable to create additonal vcxproj.user file with contents I will prepare (mainly the `<LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>` part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as there are no answers I will answer my own question since I solved the problem although I wasn't the most happy with it, since it isn't pretty I guess:

```
subprojects { subproj ->
  plugins.withId('cpp') {
    model {
      components {
        withType(NativeExecutableSpec) { c ->
          subproj.tasks.whenTaskAdded {
            if(it.name == "${c.name}VisualStudio") {

              it.dependsOn task("${c.name}_${c.name}VisualStudioUserProperties", type:Task) {

                def projectTask = tasks["${c.name}_${c.name}ExeVisualStudioProject"]
                def path = projectTask.outputs.files.singleFile.parentFile.absolutePath
                def outputPath = "${path}/${c.name}_${c.name}Exe.vcxproj.user"

                inputs.file(file("data/vsDebuggerWorkingDirectory.xml"))
                outputs.file(outputPath)

                doLast {
                  new File(outputPath).write(("${inputs.files.singleFile.text}"))
                }
                mustRunAfter "${c.name}_${c.name}ExeVisualStudioProject"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```